# Is there a Bash equivalent of Batch's msg *?

Tags: bash, batch-file, unix

In batch you can use

```
msg * Hello World
```

to give a little popup window that says Hello world. Is there an command for shell script that does the same thing?

Comment: I believe the command is `write`.

Comment: I tried "write" but it doesn't open it in a window, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

bash has not been made with GUI in mind. Different commands may be available on  different platforms, for instance:

Cygwin:

```
msg '*' Hello World
```

MacOS:

```
osascript -e 'display dialog "Hello World"'
```

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can use a (widely-available) console tool called [`dialog`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) for much more than a simple message box (like menus, lists with checkboxes, radio buttons, multiple choice dialogs, file list/selection, date/time selection, inputbox, text input, etc.). Usually interactive install scripts use it.

For example, this:

```
dialog --msgbox 'hello world' 10 30
```

will give you:

[image]

For some cool examples, check in your `/usr/share/doc/dialog/examples` directory (after installing `dialog` via your favourite package manager).

A `checklist`, `form`, `calendar`, `gauge` (progress bar) and a `fselect` (file picker) follow:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]